# Working alternatives to totcount to get the total number of pages of a document

Tags: packages, counters, totcount

I have encountered a bug in `totcount` package: sometimes it counts pages incorrectly.  For example, the following code produces for me a 2-page PDF file, but `totcount` thinks there is only one page:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{page}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

{\LARGE Total page count according to \texttt{totcount}: \total{page}.}

\end{document}
```

Is anybody still maintaining this package?

What are working alternatives to `totcount`?

I know about `lastpage` but I need the total number in numerical form, not as text.  With `totcount` I use `\totvalue{page}` for this.

Comment: Load package `lastpage` as well and you get a total of 3 pages. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `zref` that shouldn't have problems like `totcount` with respect to the page number. I mean, `totcount` is great for saving the value of counters, but it can fail with `page`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[lastpage]{zref}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for the example

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\totalpages}{\zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{page}{0}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{test}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\bigskip

\LARGE

\setcounter{test}{\totalpages}\thetest

Total page count according to \texttt{zref}: \totalpages.

\end{document}
```

As you see, you can use `\totalpages` also in context where a number is expected.

[image]

Comment: Could you give some explanation, please, why the same command sequence can be used here both as text and as a number?  For example, `\totalvalue{pages}` cannot be used this way.

Comment: @Alexey The package `zref` provides some interesting features that make possible to use reference numbers in expansion contexts like setting a counter. Of course, getting the correct reference may require one more LaTeX run, if the number of pages has changed.

Answer (score 3):

`lastpage` returns 2 as you want here

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{lastpage}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

{\LARGE Total page count according to \texttt{lastpage}: \pageref{LastPage}.}

\end{document}
```

You can use the value of `\pageref{LastPage}` as a number if you are careful.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@secondoffour#1#2#3#4{#2}
\def\getlastpage{\ifx\r@LastPage\@undefined 0\else
\expandafter\@secondoffour\r@LastPage\@empty\@empty\fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{lastpage}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

{\LARGE Total page count according to \texttt{lastpage}: \pageref{LastPage}.}

\the\numexpr\getlastpage+5\relax

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you do a numeric coparison based on the pageref value?

Comment: @Johannes_B I can, yes (as long as last page isn't numbered in roman) also it is the printed number of the last page, not the number of pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this "by hand" using the `\AtEndDocument` command from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package. The code below increments the `equation` counter at the end of the document and then creates `LastPage` label. With this in place `\pageref{LastPage}` will give the number of pages in the document (of course, you need to latex twice and the number of pages needs to be stable.

[image]

Here is the top few lines of the output from the MWE:

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% setting the LastPage label
\AtEndDocument{\refstepcounter{equation}\label{LastPage}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for illustrative purposes only below

\begin{document}

The number of pages in this document is \pageref{LastPage}.

\Blinddocument% a fake random document

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not that easy, add `\newpage` or `\clearpage` right before `\end{document}`. Then there isn't a page left for the `\label` to go and the reference remains undefined. Usually the label at the end of the document is written `\immediate`, see the implementation of packages `lastpage` or `zref-lastpage`. The latter uses the hook `\AfterLastShipout` of package `atveryend` to place the label after the last page.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I think that these corner case scenarios are user errors:) I essentially use the code above for all of my tutorials and there are never any problems.

Comment: No, these are not user errors nor corner cases. The last page can be shipped out before the label for many reasons, e.g., the last page just has ended and was output, an explicit or implicit `\newpage`, `\clearpage` et cetetera. Dealing with the implications of the asynchronous output routine is tricky. When LaTeX reaches `\end{document}`, both cases are perfectly normal and no user error, that the last page is output and is not yet output.